# OSGI - Package export not working

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, osgi, apache-felix

I am currently trying to create a modular system using the Apache Felix OSGI runtime container. And I've run into problems when trying to extend a class from a "Common" module.

I've read online that i need to export a package to make it visible outside of an OSGI bundle, however this doesn't seem to make a difference

Here is the bundle pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>ComponentTest</groupId>
<artifactId>Common</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>jar</packaging>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Export-Package>common.*</Export-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and here is the generated bundle manifest

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1519325962807
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Common
Bundle-SymbolicName: Common
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_151 (Oracle Corporation)
Export-Package: common;version="1.0.0",common.interfaces;version="1.0.0"
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5))"
Tool: Bnd-3.3.0.201609221906
```

As far as i can see the packages are shown correctly in the Export-Package line. But IntelliJ & the runtime container both throw errors.

[image]

Thanks in advance. 
If i can provide any extra information please tell me :)

Comment: What is the error shown from the runtime container? And what is TestUnit, a class in another bundle? The other bundle must have an Import-Package for the package it is using, e.g. 'common'.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in IntelliJ. OSGi is a runtime module system, does your bundle work at runtime?

Comment: Since the message is "the package... is not exported by the bundle dependencies", it's also possible that you have got the bundle dependencies incorrect. Not enough information is given here to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Just a guess. But shouldn't it be `<packaging>bundle</packaging>`?